# Horizontal Scrollbar never appears on QTableWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

I'm trying to display tabular data on a QTableWidget in PyQt5 as below.
[image: Default QTableWidget View]

I've set the columns to `QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents`.
But after the data is populated into the QTableWidget, the Horizontal Scrollbar does not appear although the 5 columns are wider than the viewport [Refer below image].
[image: First 3 columns of the QTableWidget]

However, I am able to click on a cell within the QTableWidget and drag to the right to view the last 2 columns.
[image: Last 3 columns of the QTableWidget]

I've also disabled the 'stretchLastHeaderSection' property as mentioned in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625188/qtreeview-horizontal-scrollbar-problems) regarding QTreeView, but the Horizontal Scrollbar still does not appear.

A sample python code and UI file to reproduce the issue can be found in the link below.
https://github.com/PradeepKumarN93/StackOverflowQuestions

Could someone please tell me how I can get the Horizontal Scrollbar when the contents are larger than the viewport?

Note: I'm not generating code from the ui file, but loading it directly using the following command.
`uic.loadUi(join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), "UI", "DMTInputDownloader.ui"), self)`

Thanks!

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't provide some code to start with, and from the look of your screenshots you're clearly using stylesheets. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with both the ui and python script (please, read the link: it *has* to be *both* minimal *and* reproducible).

Comment: I've added a link to a GitHub repo containing the sample python code and UI file to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please avoid using external websites to share your code and embed it in the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When styling complex widgets like QScrollBar you *must* be very careful about their properties, as in these cases changing stylesheets are responsible of drawing the *whole* widget, not just changing some parameters.

When setting all properties with pseudo selectors for sub-controls, you should consider the sizes correctly; in your case, you have set the width for the horizontal scrollbar, but you need to set its height instead:

```
QScrollBar:horizontal {              
  border: none;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Also note that you should set a layout for the central widget too, otherwise the contents won't be properly resized: if the window is too big, the widgets will still be on the top left of the window leaving a lot of unused space, and if the window is too small some controls would be partially (if not completely) hidden. See [How to make a Qt Widget grow with the window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044836/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-grow-with-the-window-size/6045152).

Comment: That worked perfectly! And followed your suggestion regarding the use of layout for the central widget as well. Thanks!